# Find whether 2 arrays are permutations of each other recursively in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, permutation

I need to build a recursive function that returns `true` if array `a` is permutation of array `b` and `false` otherwise.

```
public static boolean isPermutation (int [] a, int [] b)
```

- Can add arguments to the function.
- Can NOT use local array.
- Can NOT use loops.
- Can NOT use library functions.
- Can NOT change the arrays.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `return Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(a), Arrays.sort(b))`

Comment: @SMA can't use library functions

Comment: You could recurse through list a, comparing each element in a with b to see if b also has that element, if it doesn't return false, if you have no more elements, return true

Comment: @dbrown93 and if a = {1,2,3,4,4} b = {4,2,4,1,3}?

Comment: @Zvikivex I don't really know what you're asking. A naive solution would be to recurse for each element in the first list, then either have another method that recurses through b to see if that element from a is in b, or use a for loop to see if that element is in b

Comment: Was my answer a good answer for you, Zviki?

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you, it's basically a loop implemented with recursion.  This should execute in quadratic time.

```
public static boolean isPermutation(int[] a, int[] b, boolean[] ataken, boolean[] btaken, int iter, int totalTaken, int aidx, int bidx)
{
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    // totalTaken is a count of the number of matches we've "taken"
    if(totalTaken == a.length) return true;

    // don't "loop" b
    if(bidx >= b.length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // we should loop through a... this will yield a quadratic runtime speed
    if(aidx >= a.length)
    {
        if (iter < a.length)
        {
            return isPermutation(a, b, ataken, btaken, iter + 1, totalTaken, 0, bidx);
        }

        // finished our loop, and "totalTaken" wasn't the whole array
        return false;
    }

    // found a match for this b[bidx]
    if(a[aidx] == b[bidx] && !ataken[aidx] && !btaken[bidx])
    {
        ataken[aidx] = true;
        btaken[bidx] = true;
        return isPermutation(a, b, ataken, btaken, iter, totalTaken + 1, aidx + 1, bidx + 1);
    }

    // loop through a
    return isPermutation(a, b, ataken, btaken, iter, totalTaken, aidx + 1, bidx);
}
```

You call it with `ataken` and `btaken` arrays filled with `false`, but of the same length as `a` and `b`, respectively.

```
var isPerm = staticClassName.isPermutation(a, b, ataken, btaken, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is the following: it's a permutation if the product of all members in `a` is equal to the product of all members in `b` AND the sum of all members in `a` is equal to the sum of all members in `b`.

Write a recursive helper function that will allow you to compute these sums and products and compare them.

Complexity: O(n)

Caveat: can overflow if dealing with many large numbers

**See the comments for an important point made by John Carpenter**

Comment: Your premise: Given `p` and `s`, if `x*y*z*... = p` and `x+y+z+... = s`, then there is a unique `x`, `y`, `z`, `...` that fulfills this requirement, but this is false.  For instance, `[2,3,4]` and `[1,2,6]` would be permutations with this algorithm!

Comment: However, the idea is still a good one I think, but instead of `*` and `+`, you could conceivable create a commutative hashing function which takes a stream of inputs and outputs a value (perhaps an integer).  Then you'd have very low probability of a false positive, but still there could be a collision because of the pigeon hole principle.  `n^m > n`.

Comment: Good point, actually - thank you. I'll leave the answer to keep your comment.